# C++ named arguments, like C#

Tags: c#, c++

In later versions of C#, there is the concept of [named arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739(v=vs.120).aspx), such as this:

```
static int CalculateBMI(int weight, int height)
{
    return (weight * 703) / (height * height);
}
. . .
var a = CalculateBMI(weight:100, height:60);
```

Does such a concept exist in C++, and if so, how is it used?

Researched thus far:
Kernighan & Ritche, "C Programming Language" 2nd ed (okay, I know it's C, but still a good starting point)
[C++.com search](http://www.cplusplus.com/search.do?q=named%20argument)
[google search](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=C%2B%2B%20%22named%20argument%22)
SO search

Comment: There is no native support for it. Boost has an attempt for it. Every hack has its drawbacks

Comment: This question seems fine to me. I don't know why there was a downvote. Hopefully it will be explained.

Comment: it shows no research.

Comment: @DanielA.White I agree, but so does every other basic language question on SO that has 3000 upvotes.

Comment: @DanielA.White I will edit to show the research I've done thus far...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076786/why-c-doesnt-support-named-parameter

Comment: A quick google search would show it is not supported by the language.  No reason to ask after doing that. (not the down voter)

Comment: Ok, now I know. But just want to register but for someone not familiar with C++ this is not as easy to find out as everyone seems to think. Even the title of the duplicate question has several words that throw off the scent of what I'm basically after, ie "Boost", "Idiom".

Comment: Sure it is. All I did was type "named parameter c++" into the Stack Overflow search.

Comment: There exists a better concept in c++ namely http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal making your parameters typesafe.